# nobody@mycraftmail.com - Anyone came through this email Address?

Tags: amazon-web-services, phishing

In my site nobody@mycraftmail.com email coming suspiciously.

Don't know how above email gets coming. But, when I cross-checked those request. Those are from Amazon AWS IP(54.71.187.124). On googled further, found that email is in phishing database.

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mitchellkrogza/Phishing.Database/master/phishing-links-ACTIVE.txt

Did anyone have an idea about it?

Comment: see that on my site as well

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not a programming question.

Answer (score 3):

If you send out links from your site that have an email address it might be related to this. 
https://github.com/surbo/knockknock/blob/master/README.md

Answer (score 0):

basically, the phishing list you sent is not like suspicious emails or sender. The phishing list that includes that email, like this "http://amadermanikganj.com/Cpanelreport/equos/index.php?email=nobody@mycraftmail.com" indicates that in the param someone tried it with that email. not related to phish and suspicious activity